# ruby gem that could generate prawn code from given pdf

Tags: ruby, prawn

is there any gem that generates ruby code from a given pdf?

what I am looking for is exactly opposite of prawn, I do not wish to write ruby code to generate pdf using prawn, instead was just curious to know if there is any anti-prawn like gem that would generate prawn ruby code for me given a sample pdf :)

Comment: what are you really trying to solve? whats the real business requirement?

Comment: you can parse pdf files and extract content, text/images/tables/urls...

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. That's simply too hard of a task.